# How to use ngx-bootstrap in Angular 4 application with SystemJs module system

Tags: angular, systemjs, ngx-bootstrap

I have tried out many variations of specifying path for allowing SystemJS to load the ngx-bootstrap package

```
    System.config({
    "defaultJSExtensions": true,
    "paths": {

        "@angular/core": "node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
        "@angular/forms": "node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js",
        "@angular/http": "node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js",
        ...
        "*": "node_modules/*",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap",
        "highcharts": "node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js",
        "angular2-highcharts": "node_modules/angular2-highcharts/index.js"
    },
    "packages": {}
});
```

But still it won't load properly..

I see following error in the console

```
"(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap.js 

wrapFn@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1493823577322:1230:30 [<root>]       

Error loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap.js as "ngx-bootstrap" from http://localhost:5555/hc/app.module.js" 

"Not expecting this error? Report it at https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing this part:

```
packages: {
  //... other code
  'ngx-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
}
```

Demo here: https://github.com/valor-software/angular2-quickstart/blob/e9ea3dfd6ea48acf40a99e8e0ab1c9908f3467cd/systemjs.config.js#L22

Comment: Your solution is correct. But with Angular seed project... I need it to project.config.ts like below
`let additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [{
        name: 'ngx-bootstrap',
        path: 'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.min.js'
      }, {
        name: 'highcharts',
        path: 'node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js'
      },
      {
        name: 'angular2-highcharts',
        path: 'node_modules/angular2-highcharts/index.js'
      }];

     this.addPackagesBundles(additionalPackages);`

Comment: Adding just 'ngx-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js' under the map declaration worked for me without doing the additional package declaration.